# Loop thru a filename list and iterate thru a variable/array removing all strings from filenames with bash

Tags: arrays, bash, macos, special-characters, nested-loops

I have a list of strings that I have in a variable and would like to remove those strings from a list of filenames. I'm pulling that string from a file that I can add to and modify over time. Some of the strings in the variable may include part of the item needed to be removed while the other may be another line in the list. Thats why I need to loop thru the entire variable list.

I'm familiar using a while loop to loop thru a list but not sure how I can loop thru each line to remove all strings from that filename.

Here's an example:

```
getstringstoremove=$(cat /text/from/some/file.txt)
echo "$getstringstoremove"

# Or the above can be an array
getstringstoremove=$(cat /text/from/some/file.txt)
declare -a arr=($getstringstoremove)
```

the above 2 should return the following lines

```
-SOMe.fil
(Ena)M-3_1
.So[Me].filEna)M-3_2
SOMe.fil(Ena)M-3_3
```

Here's the loop I was running to grab all filenames from a directory and remove anything other than the filenames

```
ls -l "/files/in/a/folder/" | awk -v N=9 '{sep=""; for (i=N; i<=NF; i++) {printf("%s%s",sep,$i); sep=OFS}; printf("\n")}' | while read line; do 
echo "$line"
```

returns the following result after each loop

```
# 1st loop 
ilikecoffee1-SOMe.fil(Ena)M-3_1.jpg
# iterate thru $getstringstoremove to remove all strings from the above file.
# 2nd loop
ilikecoffee2.So[Me].filEna)M-3_2.jpg
# iterate thru $getstringstoremove again
# 3rd loop
ilikecoffee3SOMe.fil(Ena)M-3_3.jpg
# iterate thru $getstringstoremove and again
done
```

the final desired output would be the following

```
ilikecoffee1.jpg
ilikecoffee2.jpg
ilikecoffee3.jpg
```

I'm running this in bash on Mac.
I hope this makes sense as I'm stuck and can use some help.

If someone has a better way of doing this by all means it doesn't have to be the way I have it listed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the new filenames with this awk one-liner:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {for(i in a){n=index($0,i);if(n){$0=substr($0,0,n-1)substr($0,n+length(i))}}} 1' rem.txt files.lst
```

This assumes your exclusion strings are in `rem.txt` and there's a files list in `files.lst`.

Spaced out for easier commenting:

```
NR==FNR {               # suck the first file into the indices of an array,
  a[$0]
  next
}

{
  for (i in a) {        # for each file we step through the array,
    n=index($0,i)       # search for an occurrence of this string,
    if (n) {            # and if found,
      $0=substr($0,0,n-1)substr($0,n+length(i))
                        # rewrite the line with the string missing,
    }
  }
}

1                       # and finally, print the line.
```

If you stow the above script in a file, say `foo.awk`, you could run it as:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk rem.txt files.lst
```

to see the resultant files.

Note that this just shows you how to build new filenames. If what you want is to ***do*** this for each file in a directory, it's best to avoid running your renames directly from awk, and use shell constructs designed for handling files, like a `for` loop:

```
for f in path/to/*.jpg; do
  mv -v "$f" "$(awk -f foo.awk rem.txt - <<<"$f")"
done
```

This should be pretty obvious except perhaps for the `awk` options, which are:

- `-f foo.awk`, use the awk script from this filename,
- `rem.txt`, your list of removal strings,
- `-`, a hyphen indicating that standard input should be used IN ADDITION to `rem.txt`, and
- `<<<"$f"`, a "here-string" to provide that input to awk.

Note that this awk script will work with both gawk and the non-GNU awk that is included in macos.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks so much for the details and comments, really helped out. =)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have understood what you mean, and I would do it with Perl which comes built-in to the standard `macOS` - so nothing to install.

I assume you have a file called `remove.txt` with your list of stuff to remove, and that you want to run the script on all files in your current directory. If so, the script would be:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;

# Load the strings to remove into array "strings"
my @strings = `cat remove.txt`;
for(my $i=0;$i<$#strings;$i++){
   # Strip carriage returns and quote metacharacters - e.g. *()[] 
   chomp($strings[$i]);
   $strings[$i] = quotemeta($strings[$i]);
}

# Iterate over all filenames
my @files = glob('*');
foreach my $file (@files){
   my $new = $file;
   # Iterate over replacements
   foreach my $string (@strings){
      $new =~ s/$string//;
   }
   # Check if name would change
   if($new ne $file){
      if( -f $new){
         printf("Cowardly refusing to rename %s as %s since it involves overwriting\n",$file,$new);
      } else {
         printf("Rename %s as %s\n",$file,$new);
         # rename $file,$new;
      }
   }
}
```

Then save that in your `HOME` directory as `renamer`. Make it executable - only necessary once - with this command in Terminal:

```
chmod +x $HOME/renamer
```

Then you can go in any directory where you madly named files are and run the script like this:

```
cd path/to/mad/files
$HOME/renamer
```

As with all things you download off the Internet, make a backup first and just run on a small, copied, subset of your files till you get the idea of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **homebrew** as your package manager, you could install `rename` using:

```
brew install rename
```

You could then take all the Perl from my other answer and condense it down to a couple of lines and embed it in a `rename` command which would give you the added benefit of being able to do dry-runs etc. The code below does exactly the same as my other answer but is somewhat harder to read for non_perl folk.

Your command would simply be:

```
rename --dry-run '
   my @strings = map { s/\r|\n//g; $_=quotemeta($_) } `cat remove.txt`;
   foreach my $string (@strings){ s/$string//; } ' *
```

**Sample Output**

```
'ilikecoffee(Ena)M-3_1' would be renamed to 'ilikecoffee'
'ilikecoffee-SOMe.fil' would be renamed to 'ilikecoffee'
'ilikecoffee.So[Me].filEna)M-3_2' would be renamed to 'ilikecoffee'
```

To try and understand it, remember:

- the `rename` part applies the following Perl to each file because of the asterisk at the end
- the `@strings` part reads all the strings from the file `remove.txt` and removes any carriage returns and linefeeds from them and quotes any metacharacters
- the `foreach` applies each of the deletions to the current filename which `rename` stores in `$_` for you

---

Note that this method trades simplicity for performance somewhat. If you have millions of files to do, the other method will be quicker because here I read the `remove.txt` file for each and every file whose name is checked, but if you only have a few hundred/thousand files, I doubt you'll notice it.

---

This should be much the same, just shorter:

```
rename --dry-run '
   my @strings = `cat remove.txt`; chomp @strings;
   foreach my $string (@strings){ s/\Q$string\E//; } ' *
```